# How to create new demon.model in openGLES?

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es, model

I want to create a rotating object with 3d effect , I am using the sample project iPhoneGLEssentials provided by developer.apple.com. In the sample project demon.model file is used , I need to create my own .model file. Can any one help me how to create the required .model file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see from the source for that demo that's not a common format. It just has the arrays for positions, normals, texcoords and element indices. You can see how it is read from the .model file in the `moduleUtil.h`. You can search online for libraries that can load specific formats for models. Engines like [irrlicht](http://irrlicht.sourceforge.net/) has support for many formats such as .3ds, and .x. You can start from checking there.